sql server query to show the running jobs - what about the steps of the job?
I have been working on a query to show me the running jobs.
I got it right.
the script is below (enjoy):
DECLARE @JOB_NAME SYSNAME=NULL

    SELECT  job.name
            ,job.job_id
            ,StepName=CASE WHEN ja.Last_Executed_Step_ID IS NULL THEN js.Step_Name ELSE js2.Step_Name END
            ,job.originating_server
            ,ja.run_requested_date

            ,[Step Executing]=CASE WHEN ja.last_executed_step_id IS NULL
                                 THEN 'Step 1 executing'
                                 ELSE 'Step ' + convert(varchar(20),  last_executed_step_id + 1)
                                      + ' executing'
                             END

            ,[Running For] = CASE WHEN RADHE.YEARS > 0 THEN CAST( RADHE.YEARS AS VARCHAR(20) ) + ' Anni ' ELSE '' END + 
                            CASE WHEN RADHE.MONTHS> 0 THEN CAST( RADHE.MONTHS AS VARCHAR(20) ) + ' Mesi ' ELSE '' END + 
                            CASE WHEN RADHE.WEEKS> 0 THEN CAST( RADHE.WEEKS AS VARCHAR(20) ) + ' Settimane ' ELSE '' END + 
                            CASE WHEN RADHE.DAYS> 0 THEN CAST( RADHE.DAYS AS VARCHAR(20) ) + ' Giorni ' ELSE '' END + 
                            CASE WHEN RADHE.HOURS> 0 THEN CAST( RADHE.HOURS AS VARCHAR(20) ) + ' Ore ' ELSE '' END + 
                            CASE WHEN RADHE.MINUTES> 0 THEN CAST( RADHE.MINUTES AS VARCHAR(20) ) + ' Minuti ' ELSE '' END + 
                            CASE WHEN RADHE.SECONDS> 0 THEN CAST( RADHE.SECONDS AS VARCHAR(20) ) + ' Secondi ' ELSE '' END 
                                      


    FROM    msdb.dbo.sysjobs_view job WITH(NOLOCK)

            INNER JOIN msdb.dbo.sysjobactivity ja WITH(NOLOCK)
                    ON job.job_id = ja.job_id

            INNER JOIN msdb.dbo.syssessions sess  WITH(NOLOCK)
                    ON sess.session_id = ja.session_id

            INNER JOIN ( 
            
                            SELECT   MAX(agent_start_date) AS max_agent_start_date
                             FROM     msdb.dbo.syssessions WITH(NOLOCK)

                       ) sess_max ON sess.agent_start_date = sess_max.max_agent_start_date


            LEFT OUTER JOIN msdb.dbo.SysJobSteps js WITH (nolock) 
                         ON (job.Job_ID = js.Job_ID
                        AND ISNULL(ja.Last_Executed_Step_ID, job.Start_Step_ID) = js.Step_ID)

            LEFT OUTER JOIN msdb.dbo.SysJobSteps js2 WITH (nolock) 
                         ON (js.Job_ID = js2.Job_ID
                        AND (js.On_Success_Step_ID = js2.Step_ID
                         OR (js.On_Success_Action = 3 AND js.Step_ID + 1 = js2.Step_ID)))

           CROSS APPLY(


                                SELECT      FLOOR ( UpTime / 31207680 ) AS YEARS
                                        ,   FLOOR( (UpTime / 2600640 ) - FLOOR ( UpTime / 31207680  )  * 12 ) AS MONTHS
                                        ,   FLOOR( (UpTime / 604800 ) - FLOOR ( UpTime / 2600640 )  * 4.3 ) AS WEEKS
                                        ,   FLOOR( (UpTime / 86400 ) - FLOOR( UpTime / 604800 ) * 7 ) AS DAYS
                                        ,   FLOOR( ( UpTime / 3600 ) - FLOOR( UpTime / 86400 ) * 24 ) AS HOURS
                                        ,   FLOOR( ( UpTime / 60 )   - FLOOR( UpTime / 3600 ) * 60 ) AS MINUTES
                                        ,   UpTime - FLOOR( UpTime / 60 ) * 60 AS SECONDS

                                FROM        ( 
                                
                                                SELECT DATEDIFF(SECOND, ja.run_requested_date, GETDATE()) AS UpTime 
                                                  FROM  msdb.dbo.sysjobactivity Govinda WITH(NOLOCK)
                                                WHERE   Govinda.job_id     = ja.job_id
                                                  AND   Govinda.session_id = sess.session_id


                                                
                                             ) AS RadheX


                      ) Radhe 

    WHERE   run_requested_date IS NOT NULL
            AND stop_execution_date IS NULL
            AND ((@JOB_NAME IS NULL) OR (job.name LIKE @JOB_NAME))


this is the result I get:

That is all correct as my current environment and time, however,
the duration is of the entire job.
this one hour and something refers to how long the job has been running, not only this particular step that shrinks the database.
How can I find out, the total job duration (as it is) and the duration specifically for the step that is currently running?

Take a look at msdb.dbo.sysjobhistory which stores the step and runtime for each step in the job.  There is status column (in progress, succeeded, failed, etc.) and a duration column.  sysjobhistory

@MarcelloMiorelli have you figured out how to view Steps, total duration of Job and duration of steps specifically? if so, could you post the updated query for viewing the jobs along with steps ?

@AlekseyVitsko it is on my list, but other things have taken priority, apologies pal

I wrote the following query to list whole jobs duration and dates, times.
declare @job_id uniqueidentifier  ='52B11298-F14A-436E-9313-2DE54B78B37F'

select j.name Job_Name, 
h.run_date [Date],
h.run_time [Time], 
h.run_duration [Duration (sec)], 
convert(varchar(8), dateadd(second, run_duration, 0), 108)  [Duration (hh:mm:ss)]      
from 
msdb.dbo.sysjobhistory h left join
msdb.dbo.sysjobs j on h.job_id=j.job_id    
where j.job_id=@job_id
and 
step_id=0    
union all
select Job_Name,Run_Date,[Time],[Duration (sec)],[Duration (hh:mm:ss)] 
from
(
select top 1 j.name Job_Name, 
    convert(int,convert(nvarchar(10),start_execution_date,112)) [Run_Date],
    convert(int,replace(convert(varchar(8), start_execution_date, 108),':','')) [Time], 
    convert(int,replace(convert(varchar(8), getdate()-start_execution_date, 108),':','')) [Duration (sec)],     
    convert(varchar(8), getdate()-start_execution_date, 108) [Duration (hh:mm:ss)]  
from 
msdb.dbo.sysjobs j
left join msdb.dbo.sysjobactivity a on a.job_id=j.job_id 
where j.job_id=@job_id and
Convert(int,Convert(nvarchar(10),start_execution_date,112))>=(select max(h.run_date) from msdb.dbo.sysjobhistory h where h.job_id=@job_id
)
and a.job_history_id is null
order by session_id desc
) Tac    
order by  h.run_date,h.run_time

It shows the following result when job is not running.

While the job is running the result is as follows.

When you refresh the query, the job duration proceeds.

After the job complation the result is as follows.

